# Vuex — handling network busy status globally?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue/Vuex app and I'm using a Boolean `networkBusyStatus` to store when API calls are being done.

I have a lot of different calls firing when the app loads so when I watch `networkBusyStatus` in one of my components and console the newVal, it's predictably alternating true, false, true, false.

What's the correct way of globally watching this to know when "false" is really the *final* "false". i.e. loading is officially and completely done?

Comment: Instead of a boolean, use a counter that increases when loading starts and decreases when loading ends. Or a list of strings that you push to, so you can tell what is still loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Promise.all` method to ensure that the `networkBusyStatus` state is mutated only when all the API calls have been resolved.

#### .vue file

```js
export default {
  mounted() { // as you know, the created hook can also be used here
    this.$store.commit('loading', true)
    Promise.all([this.$store.dispatch('fetchAsyncData'), this.$store.dispatch('fetchAnotherAsyncDataOnTheSameComponent')]).then(values => {
     this.$store.commit('loading', false) // commit a mutation for changing networkBusyStatus to false when all requests have been resolved
  })
}
```

#### vuexModule.js

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    networkStatusBusy: false // you can share networkStatusBusy state so that when multiple api calls are made on  the same component, networkStatusBusy doesn't return to false until all calls are resolved.
    data: [],
    otherAsyncData: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    loading (state, payload) {
      state.networkStatusBusy = payload
    }
    setAsyncData(state, payload) {
      state.data = payload;
    }
    setOtherAsyncData(state, payload) {
      state.otherAsyncData = payload;
    }
  }
  actions: {
    fetchAsyncData ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('path-to-api').then(result => {
        commit ('setAsyncData', result.data)
      })
    }
    fetchAnotherAsyncDataOnTheSameComponent ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('another-api-on-same-component').then(result => {
        commit('setOtherAsyncData', result.data);
      })
    }
  }

})
```

#### .vue file

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  // ...
  computed: mapState({
    networkBusyStatus: state => state.(moduleInQuestion).networkBusyStatus,
  }),
  watch: {
    networkBusyStatus function (newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('new value', newVal)
    }
  }
}
```